# Where is the best place to register listeners to JButtons created from arrays?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton

I'm creating some JButtons from a String array for a menu. Those buttons are created in a class that extends JButton. On creation, the buttons call a method to create some children buttons (if the parent button has a submenu to display).

I'd like to be able to register listeners to every single button. Each button is going to either change the JPanel currently displayed or open up its submenu. I thought I'd register the listener in the constructor, but I read some articles I found on Google that it was bad practice to do so.

What I'd like to know is where the best place to do this would be, because I have no idea what's good practice and what's not when registering listeners.

Comment: 1) Why do these articles say that it's bad practice to register listeners in a constructor, and 2) Why does your class subclass JButton? Does it override one of JButton's methods?

Comment: It says it's bad practice because it might cause thread-safety issues because it lets the "this" reference escape before the object is fully constructed. I don't know enough about thread-safety to know if it's true, which is why I asked. As for subclassing JButton, I'm actually adding methods to make oddly-shaped buttons clickable only on non-transparent pixels and also to make it easier to see the parent-children relationships between various custom JButtons. I'm pretty sure my solution is sub-optimal, but it works and I didn't know how to implement it better,

Comment: I don't see how it would be bad practice, especially if you do all of this on the EDT.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the article then, it seemed like the best way to do so but I was getting a headache just thinking about how I was supposed to register the listeners instead, which would have made it a lot more complicated. Thanks! If you submit this as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I'd like to read the article first. Is it online? Can you post a link?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07265/index.html   The part I'm talking about is under "Initialization safety risks"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I know what's confusing you.  This article: [Java theory and practice: Be a good (event) listener](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07265/index.html) states that it is bad practice to register a listener from *its* constructor, but what they mean is the *listener's* constructor, not the button' constructor. It should be fine to register a listener from within the JButton's constructor. Your listener will likely be an anonymous inner class or an inner private class (or if complex, a stand alone class), so this is not really an issue.

**edit**
Except you can have problems if you do this and then subclass your buttons.

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot for clarifying that. Now I feel stupid I didn't read it more carefully. Sorry about wasting your time, your help if really appreciated.